# What is the output of the following program? How do you trace such a program?

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

I have to determine the output of the program below. The answer is `B E A D C`, but i'm not sure how to trace the program. Here's is what i know:

We start off by declaring a structure called `road_trip` with data type `trip`. In the main program we assign values to the member `place`. Then a linked list is created where the starting node is `s2` and ending node is `s3`. Because you can see that the address of starting node is being stored in a separate pointer `ptr` which is often known as head pointer. `s3` is the ending of the linked list because if you see the `s3` you may notice that `next` of `s3` is `NULL`. That means `s3` is not referring any other node.

What I don't understand is how does the program prints the values stored in `s2` (`B`), `s5` (`E`), `s1` (`A`), `s4` (`D`), and `s3` (`C`) in that order. I'm sure it has to do with the two lines I wrote comments after. An explanation would be of great help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct road_trip
{
    char place;
    struct road_trip* next;
}trip;

int main (void)
{
    trip s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6;
    trip *ptr;

    s1.place = 'A';
    s2.place = 'B';
    s3.place = 'C';
    s4.place = 'D';
    s5.place = 'E';

    s5.next = &s1;
    ptr = &s2;
    s1.next = &s4;
    s3.next = NULL;
    s4.next = &s3;
    s2.next = &s5;

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c ", ptr -> place);    /*I don't get this line*/
        ptr = ptr -> next;    /*I don't get this line*/
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  you can simply run it and see fit yourself.

Comment: It is called a "linked list". *"next" of s3 is NULL* - that is why `'C'` is the last to be printed.

Comment: "How do you trace such a program" - the same way as any other program. But you have to understand pointers first, which you apparently don't.

Comment: 'what is the output`.   Have you tried anything really simple, like running the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> printf("%c ", ptr -> place);    /*I don't get this line*/
> ptr = ptr -> next;    /*I don't get this line*/
> ```

- Here, `ptr` is a pointer to the `trip` *(i.e,* `struct road_trip`*)*.
- when you want to access the members of a structure using a pointer, then `->` (**[Structure dereference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator)** operator) operator is used

---

> The answer is "B E A D C", but i'm not sure how to trace the program.

```
s5.next = &s1;
ptr = &s2;
s1.next = &s4;
s3.next = NULL;
s4.next = &s3;
s2.next = &s5;
```

The above part of the code is useful to trace the program...

Here

- `ptr` points to `s2`

and:

- `next` member of `s2` points to `s5`
- `next` member of `s5` points to `s1`
- `next` member of `s1` points to `s4`
- `next` member of `s4` points to `s3`
- `next` member of `s3` points to `NULL`

*You've given the correct explanation in your question*

---

> What I don't understand is how does the program prints the values stored in `s2` (B), `s5` (E), `s1` (A), `s4` (D), and `s3` (C) in that order

Now when you iterate using `ptr` this way :

```
while (ptr != NULL)
{
    printf("%c ", ptr -> place);
    ptr = ptr -> next;
}
```

**Tracing the loop :**

> - on **first iteration** `B` gets printed because `ptr` points to `s2` and thus `ptr->place` is same as  `s2.place` *(so using the **[Structure dereference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator)** operator the values of `place` member accessed)*

- then `ptr = ptr->next` is same as `ptr = s2->next` and thus `ptr = &s5` as `s2->next` points to `s5`
- Similarly, this loop continues and you get the output in the way their `next` members are connected
- The loop ends after printing `s3` because `s3->next` points to `NULL` and thus `ptr` becomes `=NULL` after printing `s3`

---

**Further reading :**

- This is a typical implementation of **[linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)** *(click to know more)*.
- This type of list where one member of structure points to next structure of the list is known as **[singly linked list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html)** *(click to know more)*.

Answer (score 0):

ptr is a pointer to s2, so displaying char ptr->place will display place of trip s2. Then ptr is being changed to next pointer - next of s2 is s5. Displaying ptr -> place will display now place of trip s5. Then ptr changes to next of s5, which is s1 and it goes untill it reaches s3, which next pointer is NULL.